# Creating an ArrayList of Arraylist of paths for a Binary Tree?

Tags: java, binary-tree

I've searched this problem up before but looking at answers to previous problems doesn't seem to help me, and I'm not sure how to test my function on a binary tree because you can't add to a binary tree (I think?)

Basically, for practice examples for an upcoming exam, my professor gave us a problem to make an arraylist of arraylists of all possible paths to a null node. If the path includes going to the left, put a 0 in the array list, and if the path goes to the right, put a 1.

For example:
In a binary tree that prints as:

7

--1

----2

------null

------null

----3

------null

------null

--null

the function should produce: 
[[0,0,0], [0,0,1], [0,1,0], [0,1,1],[1]].

The code that I have made is:

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> paths() {
    return paths(root);     
}

public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> newPath(Node<E> n, ArrayList<Integer> path, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> allPaths) {
    Node<E> current = n;
    //ArrayList<Integer> path = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    if (current != null) {
        if (current.left != null) {
            path.add(0);            
            newPath(current.left, path,allPaths);           
        }

        if (current.right != null) {
            path.add(1);            
            newPath(current.right, path, allPaths);
        }
    }       
    allPaths.add(path);
    return allPaths;        
}

public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> paths(Node<E> n) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> allPaths = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    ArrayList<Integer> path = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    return newPath(n, path, allPaths);      
}
```

Is this the right way to go about it? I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how to use recursion on binary trees for stuff like this.
Also, how would I test it? I know how to create and add to a binary search tree, but when it comes to a binary tree I'm completely lost.

Thank you for any advice you can provide, and if there is anything I could do to make this question better please let me know. I haven't asked a lot of questions on stack overflow.

Comment: Your code would be clearer if you fixed the indentation.

Comment: I fixed it a little, is there anything else I should change?

Comment: Yes -- get rid of unnecessary blank lines and make sure that the indentation is correct, that is, each level of control structure is indented by 4 (or 2) spaces from the surrounding level.

Comment: "you can't add to a binary tree (I think?)" - you add nodes to a tree. It is up to you to define a node. A node can be of any type. For more help post [mcve].